# How to create an array from AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

All seems like it should be very simple but I am having issues.

I would like to create an array and list all 'questions' within the array from an AJAX response using jQuery.

I gather my thinking is out as question just returns a higher level object containing all data.

```
var questions = response.questions;
console.log(response.questions);

var question = [
  $.each(questions, function (value) {
   value.question
  })
];
```

Comment: What does `response.questions` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `response` looks like this:

```
{
    questions: [
        {question: 'A'},
        {question: 'B'},
        {question: 'C'}
    ]
}
```

and you want

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

then `.map()` is what you are looking for.

```
var question = $.map(response.questions, function (item) {
   return item.question;
});
```

Comment: How would I then map the index of the questions to get, ['0' , '1' , '2'] for example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The index is provided as the second argument to the `.map()` callback, if you need it for anything. (**Next time**, please ask a *complete* question. Input sample, corresponding desired output and a short paragraph of what you intend to do in the bigger picture. Debugging an incomplete question via the comment section is tedious and overall very inefficient.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var questions = response.questions;
console.log(response.questions);    

question = []
for(var q of questions){
    question.push(q)
}
```